# Error while trying to run the code

Tags: c, memory

Whenever I try to run the following bit of code, I get an error.[image: Image_Error]

[image: Image2_Error]
Added another error image from Visual Studio.
[image: Image3_error]
Added the exact source of error.

```
The following bit of code here is : 

void update_memblock(MEMBLOCK *mb)
{
    static unsigned char tempbuf[128 * 1024];
    unsigned int bytes_left;
    unsigned int total_read;
    unsigned int bytes_to_read;
    unsigned int bytes_read;


        bytes_left = mb->size;
        total_read = 0;


        while (bytes_left)
        {
            bytes_to_read = (bytes_left > sizeof(tempbuf)) ? sizeof(tempbuf) : bytes_left;
            ReadProcessMemory(mb->hProc, mb->addr + total_read, tempbuf, bytes_to_read, (DWORD*)&bytes_read);
            if (bytes_read != bytes_to_read) break;

            memcpy(mb->buffer + total_read, tempbuf, bytes_read);

            bytes_left -= bytes_read;
            total_read += bytes_read;
        }

        mb->size = total_read;

}



The Structure looks as follows : 
typedef struct _MEMBLOCK { 
    HANDLE hProc;   
unsigned char *addr;    
int size;   
unsigned char *buffer;
    struct _MEMBLOCK *next;

} MEMBLOCK;
```

Tried switching around quite a bit, from changing the array size to removing the variable and switching it with another, apparently it still throws this error. Kindly help me figure out where the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you checking if `mb-size > sizeof(tempbuf)`? That would eliminate one obvious cause for an error. Also, why not `DWORD bytes_to_read;` as that's another potential problem if `sizeof int < sizeof DWORD`.

Comment: You have a  struct _MEMBLOCK *next; inside its declaration , without forward declaration?

Comment: I have added the forward declaration in another part of the code, also I tried checking if mb->size >sizeof(tempbuf) and I got false to that. Tried switching to DWORD as well, still getting the error.

Comment: Have you used Valgrind?

Comment: No, currently only using visual studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the *[documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx)*, you'd notice that the arguments to `ReadProcessMemory` are **`SIZE_T`s** as they should. `DWORD` type is 32 bits and sizes 64 bits on 64-bit platform. While it doesn't matter for `bytes_to_read` as it is passed in by value, 8 bytes will be written to the pointer pointed to by `bytes_read` whose `sizeof` is 4.

Furthermore, you should get a pointer type mismatch for this, as `DWORD *` is *not* compatible with `SIZE_T *` in that case.

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem but I have one more question right here.

Comment: @TotalAnimeImmersion another question should be asked in another question. In any case, isn't *that* pointer calculated in the *another process' memory space*; the debugger shows that such address doesn't exist in *your* process.

Comment: As soon as I switched unsigned int to SIZE_T, it worked and the address started getting calculated.